# Раскодировать \u0090

Tags: кодировка

Здравствуйте. А как можно раскодировать такое `\u0090`?

Comment: А в каком контексте такое попалось? Вообще это из набора C1 control characters, запрещённого в HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Это символ в unicode под номером 90

Comment: К сему капитанскому ответу можно добавить лишь то, что это служебный символ, используемый для управления устройствами и не имеющий графического представления: [http://unicode-table.com/ru/#0090][1]

  [1]: http://unicode-table.com/ru/#0090